# How to enter a value to a element with condition on a cousin element

Tags: xml, xpath, conditional-statements

i'm trying to enter the gg value to CommercialName and i'm using the following:

`/Book/Location[@id = 'Amsterdam']/Author[AuthorInfo[Name = 'John'][Age = '51']]/BookInfo/CommlName/CommercialName`

the problem is that when creating the xml AuthorInfo is not presented.
help anyone?

```
<Book>
<Location id="Amsterdam">
<Author>
  <AuthorInfo>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>51</Age>
  </AuthorInfo>
  <BookInfo>
    <CommlName>
      <CommercialName>gg</CommercialName>
    </CommlName>
  </BookInfo>
</Author>
  </Location>
</Book>
```

Comment: *"the problem is that when creating the xml AuthorInfo is not presented"*. I still can't understand what's the problem. The XPath looks fine to return the target `CommercialName` element matching certain `AuthorInfo` criteria...

Comment: Your XPath, [when applied to your input XML](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/39edaaa82beb96d07084728ba505d663) (click to see) returns `<CommercialName>gg</CommercialName>`. If this is not what you wanted it to return, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32539498/edit) and show the expected output.

Comment: Besides, XPath is a query language, it does not have an UI, but your text suggests a user action: "enter the gg value". Please clarify.

Comment: i have a UI when i'm entering the xpath it creates the xml. but when i'm doing it i get the xml above wih name and age under "Author".

Comment: when entering the xpath i'm getting: <Book>
<Location id="Amsterdam">
<Author>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>51</Age>
  <BookInfo>
    <CommlName>
      <CommercialName>gg</CommercialName>
    </CommlName>
  </BookInfo>
</Author>
  </Location>
</Book>

Comment: i want to insert the value gg to this location using the conditions for age and name